# JFrame question

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

What code is called when a JFrame is minimized? Is it hooked up to a listener? I just want to know what happens internally when the frame is minimized.

EDIT:
Im actually looking for the code that is called when the frame is minimized. For example, the code for the actual `windowListener`. Ive been searching through `JFrame`, `Frame`, and `Window` searching for `windowIconified` but have been unable to find the actual code.

Reason being, when my program runs, it has a small defect with one of the Panels, but when I minimize and maximize the JFrame, the problem goes away. I wanted to see what was going on so that I can apply whatever is going on to my Panel so it paints right.

Comment: The tutorials will tell you all about this and give you a correct answer quicker than you can find here, but a `WindowListener` is likely what you're looking for. `windowIconified` would be called if the JFrame is minimized.  Please have a look at the [WindowListener API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) (click on link).

Comment: *"when my program runs, it has a small defect with one of the Panels, but when I minimize and maximize the JFrame, the problem goes away."*  1) Construct the GUI on the EDT.  2) Ensure that `pack()` is called prior to `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: @juser489041: You're misguided to look for a solution to your problem by looking at anything dealing with the JFrame being iconified and then de-iconified (other than this action causes the JVM to repaint the GUI). No, the real problem is why your JPanel has a "defect" to begin with, and to solve that we'll need to see code, preferably a small compilable runnable program that demonstrates the issue. Also an image or two might help.

Comment: Question: Did you fix this? Did you figure out what was wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you can listening by using WindowListener

for example

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class WinStateListener implements WindowListener {

    static JFrame window = new JFrame("Window State Listener");

    public WinStateListener() {
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.addWindowListener(this);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WinStateListener winStateListener = new WinStateListener();
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Closing");
        window.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Opened");
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Closed");
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Iconified");
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Deiconified");
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Activated");
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Deactivated");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to read about `WindowListeners` and `WindowEvents`.  The event you are talking about is called Iconifying the window.  Read more here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html

EDIT:
Use `revalidate()` then `repaint()` on the JPanel that is acting up.

Answer (score 1):

When minimizing the JFrame application a window event `windowIconified` is called.  If you want to process such window events by your own then either implement `WindowListener` interface or use `WindowAdapter` abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

> What code is called when a `JFrame` is minimized?

As noted in [*How to Make Frames: Specifying Window Decorations*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), "window decorations are supplied by the native window system." The article goes on to describe some changes you can make to the host platform's default.

Addendum: Reading your update, note that restoring an iconified window repaints it. As @Andrew Thompson points out, you may need to verify that you're building on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). You may also need to schedule a `repaint()`. An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) might clarify things.